# jquery pseudo elements not working

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery ui sortable ul and I want change the background of the list items as I move them around.

Why is this legal:

```
$("#L" + i).css('background-color', "#DCC9FF");
```

But this "works", but after the move the background color *stays blue* evan after the hover is gone:

```
$("#L" + i +":hover").css('background-color', "blue");
```

Is there a work-around?

Comment: What is `i`? Is it integer? Show your HTML. The second statement looks good, it should work.

Comment: <li class="ui-state-default" id = "L1"><input type="text" name = "N1" id = "I1" ></li>

Comment: i is an integer in a for loop.

Comment: How are you going to move the focus to an `<li>`?

Comment: I guess, the problem is that you expect `li` to be focused. You cannot focus `li` element, you can only focus buttons, radios, inputs, textareas etc.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev can't see any reason why you cannot focus `<li>` elements. Even the jQuery doco has a `<div>` example ~ https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

Comment: @verlager it's unclear what you're trying to do but I suspect you're going about it the wrong way. Can you please explain what you'd like to happen (ignoring the _"how"_)?

Comment: please add code snippet in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a special reason why you would want to use **js** to apply a hover effect? if so please consider second approach.

**FIRST**

```css
ul li {
  background-color: red
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L1"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I1" disabled class="automplete-2" /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L2"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I2" disabled class="automplete-2" /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L3"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I3" disabled class="automplete-2" /></li>
</ul>
```

**SECOND**

```js
$('ul li').css('background-color', 'red');

$('ul li').hover(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
}, function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L1"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I1" disabled class="automplete-2" /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L2"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I2" disabled class="automplete-2" /></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="L3"><input type="text" name="N1" id="I3" disabled class="automplete-2" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Absolutely first rate: simple solution, and solves the problem. I am in your debt.